# Добавить файлы в файл jar с помощью .bat либо .vbs

Tags: java, cmd, bat, vbscript

Есть java-архив main.jar в нем есть файлы и папки. Необходимо заменить целевые файлы в папке /main/core/ которая находится в архиве. Целевые файлы находятся в обычной папке. Как это реализовать в командной строке .bat или .vbs ?

Comment: возможно поможет https://habrahabr.ru/post/282934/

Comment: `jar --help`: `-u  update existing archive`

Comment: winrar точно поможет. на худой конец 7zip. только помните - надо делать zip-архив, а не ту отсебятину, которые оба предлагают по умолчанию. самый запущенный случай - встроенный в систему архиватор.

Answer (score 1):

В состав Java SDK входит архиватор jar, воспользуйтесь им. На самом деле это обычный ZIP архив, просто расширение у файла другое. Можно использовать любой архиватор, поддерживающий формат ZIP. Но надо знать что некоторые jar имеют встроенную цифровую подпись, это видно в файле MANIFEST.MF внутри архива. Если у вас такой, то после изменения работать не будет.